# Access token is valid after expiration time

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak, access-token

I have used Keycloak for access and user management system and spring boot as my resource server.

For test purposes, I set the lifespan of the access token to one minute. The problem I face is that I can access the secured APIs for exactly 60 seconds after the expiration time of the access token, then I get 401 unauthorized responses.

Can someone please explain to me the reason for this action and a solution to fix it?

---

**Edit**

Thanks to [Evil_skunk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1578780/evil-skunk), I looked for JWT validator class in spring boot, which is JwtTimestampValidator. This class implements OAuth2TokenValidator interface.

JwtTimestampValidator class has the following function for validation of JWT:

```java
public OAuth2TokenValidatorResult validate(Jwt jwt) {
    Assert.notNull(jwt, "jwt cannot be null");
    Instant expiry = jwt.getExpiresAt();
    if (expiry != null && Instant.now(this.clock).minus(this.clockSkew).isAfter(expiry)) {
        OAuth2Error oAuth2Error = this.createOAuth2Error(String.format("Jwt expired at %s", jwt.getExpiresAt()));
        return OAuth2TokenValidatorResult.failure(new OAuth2Error[]{oAuth2Error});
    } else {
        Instant notBefore = jwt.getNotBefore();
        if (notBefore != null && Instant.now(this.clock).plus(this.clockSkew).isBefore(notBefore)) {
            OAuth2Error oAuth2Error = this.createOAuth2Error(String.format("Jwt used before %s", jwt.getNotBefore()));
            return OAuth2TokenValidatorResult.failure(new OAuth2Error[]{oAuth2Error});
        } else {
            return OAuth2TokenValidatorResult.success();
        }
    }
}
```

According to this code, the function subtracts clockSkew from right now time instance then compares it with expiration instant of JWT token.

I performed a debugging test to find out the values of fields in clockSkew. I found out that the field, which is named "seconds" has a value of **60**. This value exactly matches with my observation.

I searched for the usage of JwtTimestampValidator class and its methods in my project. The usage is not found. It seems like the source code is decompiled from a jar file.

Can someone please help me to find out which part of the project sets the value of clockSkew? Is it the spring boot or the Keycloak server? Also, I want to know if it is possible to set the value of clockSkew.

Comment: I don't have experience with that specific technology, but I'd assume it uses JWT and you might be checking the values from it. If that's the case make sure that you are using the function that is both checking for validity and the insides of that token.

Comment: When you write "exactly 60 seconds after the token expires" are you referring to the `exp` claim or the time on your smartphone plus duration? Also have you checked (logged) the time inside JVMs when the JWT is issued (login) and then decoded (sent to resource-server)?

Comment: could be a configured `clock skew` in the secured API (where the JWT is checked). Clock skew is used to prevent problems if the time between servers isn't exactly the same. 60s is unusual high but can explain your observation

Comment: 60 Seconds is the default in `JwtTimestampValidator`, which might be a bit high. See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/main/oauth2/oauth2-jose/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/jwt/JwtTimestampValidator.java#L53